# ScrollToTop button displaying at the top when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my scrollToTop button to stop showing when at the top

I have the button working, as in it fades in when scrolling down, and scrolls to the top when clicked, and then hides, but if I am the top of the page and hit refresh the button displays. Is there a way to prevent this?

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#main-image" class="scrollToTop"><img src="img/up-arrow.png" class="up-arrow"/></a>
```

And my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
    }
});

//Click event to scroll to top
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},500);
    return false;
});

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: If there is nothing telling it not to appear then it will appear. Your code requires a scroll for it to fade out.

Comment: Could this be because your initial test is listening against the scroll event? A scroll event will only fire when you have actually scrolled at least a pixel, not on page load. I don't know your CSS but perhaps you should give the button an initial opacity of 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure its default setting is that it is not appearing, use CSS.

The Javscript will then take care of the rest and override this when needed.

```
.scrollToTop {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Excellent thank you Adrian! Cant believe I missed that!